# Wwan connection on Debian and/or Arch

Tags: debian, networking, arch-linux

Arch and Debian installers want internet connection but manage to install most of their load w/out it. No Linux installer I'm aware of can configure wwan. I've only a wwan connection. On Ubuntu I configure it w/ NetworkManager but Arch and Debian do not preinstall NM. So,

1. Is there a *preinstalled* way to connect to wwan on Arch and/or Debian? If so, what is it? How to configure it?
2. Perhaps you can recommend a lightweight alternative to NetworkManager? Obviously, it must be able to configure wwan connections. I don't mind moving a *few* package files on USB stick from one machine to another (NM has too many dependency packages for this)

Answer (score 0):

1) Arch linux

You should use `netcl` to use an example profile, simply copy it from `/etc/netctl/examples/ to /etc/netctl/` and configure it to your needs.

to establish a connection

```
netctl start profile
```

then it can be enabled using:

```
netctl enable profile
```

Create and enable a systemd service that will start when the computer boots

```
netctl reenable profile
```

Example profiles:

**wired connection**

For a DHCP connection, only the Interface has to be configured after copying the `/etc/netctl/examples/ethernet-dhcp` example profile to `/etc/netctl`.

```
/etc/netctl/my_dhcp_profile

 Interface=enp1s0
  Connection=ethernet
  IP=dhcp
```

**Wireless (WPA-PSK)**

The standard netctl tool to connect to a wireless network (WPA-PSK, WEP) interactively is wifi-menu:

```
wifi-menu -o
```

it generates the configuration file in `/etc/netctl/` for the network to use for #Automatic operation at the same time.
Alternatively, the profile may also be configured manually, as follows:

Copy the example file wireless-wpa from `/etc/netctl/examples` to `/etc/netctl` (name of your choice):

```
cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa /etc/netctl/
```

Edit the profile as needed (modifying Interface, ESSID and Key) and it is done.
At this step you may want to re-confirm the new profile you created is chmod 600 and confirm it works by starting it:

```
netctl start wireless-wpa
```

Source: [enter link description here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl)

2) Debian

Under Debian Linux you need to install `wpasupplicant` to support for WPA and WPA2 networks.

install

```
apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add the following lines:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid YOUR-SSID-HERE
wpa-psk YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE
```

save and exit

```
ifup wlan0
```

Restart the networking service

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and

```
dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: nmcli is NetworkManager's command line interface. So is it preinstalled on Arch or can I install it as a separate package (separate from NetworkManager)? I doubt either... Thanks for the Debian info

Comment: Agreed, nmcli = Network-Manager Command Line Interface, i will edit my answer. thank you.